# How can I send a JS variable to PHP function in Codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I want to pass a variable from JS script to PHP function on a CI Controller. I tried doing this

```
$.post(base_url+'Controller/function/', {id_formula:id_formula});
```

but I still get a CodeIgniter error

```
Message: Missing argument 1 for Controller::function()
```

Can you help me to solve it? please

Answer (score 1):

That because your controller probably looks like this:

```
function function($id_formula)
{
    ...
}
```

But you are not actually passing "id_formula" as a URL get, but as a post.
Change it to:

```
function function()
{
    $id_formula = $this->input->post('id_formula');
}
```